# Is it possible to read binary avro message with kafka REST proxy?

Tags: rest, proxy, apache-kafka, avro

I not completely understand how whole avro serialization ecosystem is built.

Originally I imagined something like that:
[image]
However, I tried to post a binary avro message message to a topic and later read it using REST proxy and got an error: `{"error_code":50002,"message":"Kafka error: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0xa126572(above 10ffff)  at char #1, byte #7)"}`.

Where am I wrong?

If it matters, I used example from [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/AvroSpecific) to write, and from [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) to read.

Comment: What content headers did you set? https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html

Comment: Brilliant! I got {"error_code":406,"message":"HTTP 406 Not Acceptable"} now, but I will see what I can do there...

Answer (score 1):

In the end turned out that I defined consumer with a [wrong format (json instead of avro)](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html). Otherwise everything works as expected. Thanks to @cricket_007 for a hint.

When creating the consumer I was doing

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
--data '{"name": "my_consumer_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}' \
http://192.168.99.101:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer
```

while the correct version is

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
--data '{"name": "my_consumer_instance", "format": "avro", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}' \
http://192.168.99.101:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer
```

Comment: You might want to update your answer with the appropriate code necessary  for the format compared to what you're using before

Answer (score -2):

Use the Kafka command line tools to produce a new Avro message to a new topic and read it back:

`/usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-producer` to produce an Avro message.

`/usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer` to consume an Avro message.

These tools are documented in the quickstart here:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart.html

Once you have that working, then make sure your custom client works with the official command line producer and make sure your custom producer works with the official command line client.

If you break it into small steps like that, you will see exactly where your problem is, have a more narrow problems to solve.

Comment: How does this answer about the REST proxy?